# Pronoun referring to noun

Tags: pronouns

In an article that gives general work advice, I've seen the following sentence

> Don’t take your complaint to your boss when **she**’s running between meetings ...

There is no context that states the gender of the boss, the author however has chosen to use **she** to refer to **boss**. Is the author here implicating that **boss** is feminine? Or does this have to do with the gender of the word **boss**?

Comment: Would you have questioned the masculine pronoun had been used?

Answer (score 0):

The word "boss" has no gender.  Presumably, in past years, such advice would have used the pronoun "he", using the convention that "he" could (in theory) refer to either gender.  But nowadays that convention is deprecated.  So this author just wrote "she" for the generic boss.  Other writers may alternate "he" and "she" for their bosses, or use the "singular *they*", or make other adjustments.